# How can I access values from schema.xml from my custom similarity implementation

Tags: java, solr, similarity, solr4

I made a very simple  custom similarity class for solr. It is mainly for testing.

```
public class StaticNormSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StaticNormSimilarity.class);
  private float norm = 0.1f;

  public void setNorm(float norm) {
    this.norm = norm;

    //TODO: not working how can I access parameters
    LOG.info("##gyk: StaticNormSimilarity norm = {}", norm);
    System.out.println(String.format("##gyk: StaticNormSimilarity: %f",norm));
  }
  public float getNorm() {
    return this.norm;
  }

  @Override
  public float queryNorm(float sumOfSquaredWeights) {
    return this.norm;
  }

}
```

In the schema.xml I do the following:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <similarity class="gyk.solr.similarity.StaticNormSimilarity">
    **HOW CAN I SEE THIS VALUE FROM MY CODE**
    <float name="norm">0.1</float>
  </similarity>
  <analyzer type="index">
  ...
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
  ...
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and

```
  <similarity class="solr.SchemaSimilarityFactory" />
```

My question is how can I see from code the `norm` value specified in the schema.xml file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [DFRSimilarityFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/4.0.0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/search/similarities/DFRSimilarityFactory.java) source code ...

For [schema](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Similarity) entry

```
  <fieldType name="text_dfr" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
    <similarity class="solr.DFRSimilarityFactory">
      <str name="basicModel">I(F)</str>
      <str name="afterEffect">B</str>
      <str name="normalization">H2</str>
    </similarity>
  </fieldType>
```

Init method allows the retrival of the params from schema.xml

```
  @Override
  public void init(SolrParams params) {
    super.init(params);
    discountOverlaps = params.getBool("discountOverlaps", true);
    basicModel = parseBasicModel(params.get("basicModel"));
    afterEffect = parseAfterEffect(params.get("afterEffect"));
    normalization = parseNormalization(
        params.get("normalization"), params.get("c"), params.get("mu"), params.get("z"));
  }
```